# Node.js pretty basic but sneaky error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gooday guys, I've a problem with Node.js. I have recently started to learn it from w3schools. But when I copied this piece of code, than the following exception occurs:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

I have **index.html** file which looks pretty basic. It shouldn't be a mess for the code.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Probably you should not ignore `err` ... and i guess its because you dont have an index.html file, therefore *data* will be `null`, and passing that to `res.write(null)` will throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't ignore errors!** ( it makes everything worse)

```
fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
```

This either passes *data* and *err* will be `null`, or if an error occurs *data* will be `null` and *err* is an `Error`. When the later happens you ignore it and do

```
res.write(data);
```

which won't work as *data* is `null` and you can't send `null` to the client ( only Buffers or Strings as said in the error).
So what to do? Well add an error handler:

```
fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
 if(err)
   return res.write(err.message);

 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.write(data);
 res.end();
});
```

So now you will probably get the real error which is

```
File not found
```

So you may check if youve got an *index.html* file.

Comment: No... It freezes. :/ And as I said previously I have the file in the same directory.

Comment: @mr phoenix what freezes ?!

Comment: It looks like the page is loading and doesn't seem to stop

Comment: Okay... now after 3 minutes of loading excepted **file** error. Thanks. I didn't know it takes another basis folder than current one :D Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening mostly because of either res.write() or res.end() either one of it accepts string as its first argument try using res.send(data) will work fine. Have a good day. Happy Learning NodeJS

Comment: Yeah... I know... I'm just checking if that works... :D

Comment: @Jonasw I made that in edit dude my bad will edit it

Comment: It says "res.send is not a function" :/

Comment: [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback): "If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned." Since no encoding was passed, to readFile, it will refurn a Buffer. Furthermore [response.write](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) accepts both a string and a Buffer.

Comment: an error saying argument must be a string so simply you need to pass `res.write(data.toString()); `

Comment: @SantoshSuryawanshi No. It does not. It says "must be a string or [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)", see above. If `data` is a Buffer, `toString()` will create a string like `<f1 5a 60 41...>`, which is the Buffer equivalent of `[Object object]`

Comment: just add `fs.readFile('index.html','utf8', function(err, data) {
 
}`

Comment: check out @jonas answer it probably because of error if it is not try with res.write("hi" + data);